# How can you get eclipse code complete for CI when using &get_instance()?

Tags: eclipse, codeigniter, autocomplete, environment-variables, eclipse-pdt

I'm currently using Eclipse PDT and CodeIgniter, is it possible to get code-completion for the sessions library like so:

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->session->se   (No auto-completion here.)
```

Also, is there some sort of plug-in (or just a method) that would allow eclipse to do this for all my CodeIgniter libraries.

**Note:** I already have support in most contexts courtesy of [this tutorial](http://abiola89.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-codeigniter-autocomplete-in.html), however I am looking specifically for when I am using a *variable* to reference CodeIgniter instead of

```
$this->
```

Thanks,

Lemiant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there seems to be a reasonable amount of interest in this; I thought I'd share my solution to this problem. Using the method from [this tutorial](http://abiola89.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-codeigniter-autocomplete-in.html) I mentioned above, you can use PHPDoc to tell the compiler that a variable is a reference to some object in your project. In this case I want $CI to reference the CI_Base object. so I declare my variable like this:

```
/**
 * @var CI_Base
 */
private $CI;
```

and voila, I have code complete (NOTE: you have to use the tutorial above to get code complete from $this->CI-> to anything else.)

Hope this helps somebody,

Lemiant